# How can I contribute to the effort to clean up Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-definition, cleanup

I've heard rumors of an cleanup effort on Christianity.SE that is in its infancy, how can I contribute so that I can assure my voice is heard from the very beginning?

Branch questions:

- [Can we reverse the trend on low quality posts?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/680)
- [What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690)
- [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692)
- [Why was my question closed? How can I get it open again?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/725)
- [Off-Topic/Not Constructive examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/777)
- [On-Topic and Constructive Examples](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/779)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to help in the cleanup effort that is beginning on Christianity.SE.

1. Join us in the [specially created chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1547/refocusing-christianity-se)
2. Comment on our [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14lrt_c_oJ742OcOEih0aTMGqDfVqMVk3i5MZJNgH1f8/edit?hl=en_US) that we are using to work out some of the upcoming meta posts.

This effort, while currently in its infancy, will hopefully help this site succeed over the long term, both in terms of popularity and usefulness and also in the eyes of the SE staff and management.