# How to fix "Do Christian Feminists view Eve as a role model?"

Tags: discussion

How do I fix the following question:

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35471/do-christian-feminists-view-eve-as-a-role-model

I feel that this question is theologically sound, yet it has -8 votes. I would like to learn how to ask this question in a way appropriate for Christianity.StackExchange.com

Thanks!

Comment: Some questions will just never be appropriate for Stack Exchange. I'm not saying this is one of those, but it might be.

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem here is that “Christian feminists” are not, really, a defined group. Both Christianity and feminism are, if you’ll pardon the expression, broad churches. There is much room for disagreement within each camp. And, while there’s a fairly large intersection between the two groups, that intersection does not really form a group in its own right.

What I’m trying to say is that your question has [scope](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690) issues. It asks about a broad and disparate range of people, with little to unite them. As Flimzy remarks in a comment,

> I’d be willing to venture there are at least two Christian feminists who consider Eve to be a role model, so the strict answer to your question would be “yes”.

You need to find a smaller group to ask about. A group with a reasonably clear boundary, and with reasonably defined beliefs and/or practices. I’m not sure that such a group of “Christian feminists” actually exists, but you might find one. In the finding, you might also find an answer to your question, but that can only be a good thing, right? And doing some research before asking a question is desirable behaviour on Stack Exchange sites anyway.

Comment: Really? You think there's 8 people downvoting due to scope issues, ..., rather than the site being overtaken by a bunch of angry feminists? :-)

Comment: @31415926 Absolutely. We downvote for scope issues all the time.

Comment: @curiousdannii http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35351/is-there-any-biblical-basis-for-saying-that-wives-should-divorce-their-physicall has even wider scope, yet is +10 votes.

Comment: @31415926 That's a biblical-basis question. They have different scope expectations (and there's some disagreement about them too.)

Comment: @curiousdannii : the question had no scope -- it asked for answers from any denominations (even those viewed heretical by reformed theology: JWs, Mormons, Catholics). However, people were happy to up vote and answer it, because they want to be a knight in shining armor and defend a hypothetical wife from being abused by a hypothetical husband.

Comment: For Biblical basis questions the scope is those who believe the doctrine in question.