# Last question was to "broad"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, catholicism

I was looking if any one knew if the church does anything at all to promote mental illness. If this is still "broad" do not worry about it.

[What does the Catholic Church do about mental illness?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/56854/what-does-the-catholic-church-do-about-mental-illness)

mod note: I moved this second post to meta to solicit reopen votes, I do not believe this question to be too broad after I edited it.

Comment: stef I'm sorry you didn't get the usual welcome on your first question. We try not to be _that_ hard on newcomers here.  I think the question is topical (at least after I edited it). Please don't post critiques of the site on the main page.  Question put on hold can be easily reopened - butnif they are put on hold it is probably because they're not going to get very good amswers in the first place and need to be reworked in such a way that they will.

Comment: for some help in finding out how to ask good questions see [this post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/691/4)

Comment: I don't think that the question as you've worded it is the one you mean to ask. I don't know of any Christian group which "promotes" mental illness., although I know of many congregations which have programs at the local level aimed at promoting "wellness", including mental wellness. I expect, though I don't know for certain, that at the national level, and at the diocesan level, the Catholic church probably has resources available to assist local parishes that want to develop these kinds of programs at the local level.

Comment: I think this question needs to be tweaked a bit to be answered.  I think I understand what the OP is asking but I believe in this case it may be to narrow of a question.  It would be easier to answer if it was more broad.  The position of the Catholic Church is not limited to a particular group of people suffering from a particular illness, rather, it is broad, like the answer to this question must be.

Comment: What research have you already done?  Who in the Catholic Church have you asked in your diocese?   Who have you talked to at your nearest parish?  Have you visted your diocese's web site?  Have you looked for a link to Catholic Charities in your Diocese?   If you can use a browser to find us you can use a browser to find your local Catholic Charities office.  The point of all this is that questions that show a bit of research are the norm for SE sites, and reflecting a bit of initial research improves the chance of getting a good answer since it will help frame the question.

Comment: stef, if English isn't your first language please let us know.  Sometime knowing that will help us to better assist a new user.

Comment: Here is a link to get you started: http://www.catholicmentalhealthproject.org.uk/

Comment: Check out PhD-in-psychology [Fr. Chad Ripperger](http://www.sensustraditionis.org/books.html)'s [_Introduction to the Science of Mental Health_](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/49246565) ([on Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Science-Mental-Health-Ripperger/dp/0615815391)), which analyzes psychology and psychological illnesses from a Catholic perspective.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, I'd recommend pinning down the types of mental illness you're interested in: depression, anxiety, PTSD, bipolar, eating disorders, self harm, personality disorders (narcissism etc), gender and body dysphoria, the list goes on. This is why the question is too broad. If you can limit it to one or two closely related things then we'll be able to address it on this site.