# how could I be labeled a anti-semite when I am Jewish (semitic) myself?

Tags: discussion

I answered the question about what the "abomination of desolation" was and David Stratton labled me as being anti-semetic and locked the comments to my answer, I love David Stratton and his insight but I am surprised at his harsh judgement of me. I am Jewish and love the Jewish people I just dont agree with the fact that the Orthodox Jews teach against Jesus Christ and his "Messiah status" does that make me anti-semetic? Also why is it that as soon as you say something contrary to the Orthodox Jews that your labeled as anti-Semetic? As I said before, I am a Semite so how could I hate myself?

Comment: The answer in question is [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7266/what-is-the-abomination-of-desolation/32188#32188). (It's deleted.)

Comment: Can you please quote your full answer here for those of us who can't see it?

Comment: @curiousdannii - I updated my answer to contain his full answer.

Comment: It is important for everyone to understand that anti-Semite is a strictly political term that has nothing to do with religion. It is a very specific term that should not be used incorrectly. An anti-Semite is anyone that politically treats Jews differently to other people. Jews can claim that Jews deserve special treatment because of the Holocaust - that is anti-Semitic. Jews can claim that Israelis are evil - that is anti-Semitic.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps antisemitic was the wrong term to use. However, you still leveled a statement that claimed that the "Abomination of desolation" was European Jews.

The answer was:

---

The abomination of desolation standing in the holy place is the orthodox European jews who are anti (against) christ. They not only reject jesus as the messiah but also teach against him entirely while being owners of jerusalem (the holy land) which should be the main place where the messiah should be proclaimed.

This is also spoken of in Revelations 2:9

“I know about your
suffering and your
poverty—but you are
rich! I know the
blasphemy of those
opposing you. They say
they are Jews, but they
are not, because their
synagogue belongs to
Satan.

revelations 2:9

---

My comments when deleting were:

This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Also, I don't see how you draw the conclusion that this is talking about European Jews. There's nothing at all saying that this is the Jews, and we really don't need unfounded antisemitism here on this site.

---

Whether your claim is against all Jews or just the European ones doesn't matter.  The "answer"singles out a group and goes on to explain how that group is "the bad guys".  It still has no business on this site.

You may feel that you are "correct" in your view, but it's still disallowed.  Not just because it's inflammatory but because you did absolutely nothing to indicate that the idea that the European Jews were the abomination of desolation was anything other than your own personal opinion.

Had you found a teaching from any group and said "According to _______ the abomination of desolation is the European Jews"and then provided quotes from that group, the answer would have stood.  I wouldn't have voted it up or down, I'd have just ignored it, because that ***would*** have fallen in with the guidelines of the site.

Comment: Indeed and I strongely respect you and your perspective David thank you for clarification of your reception of my answer, I meant it in no hate or disrespect when I answered as such, rather instead sincere disappointment in my fellow Jewish brothers in Israel for being against our Adonai (Lord) and saviour Melech haMoshiach Yeshua (The King Jesus Christ).

Comment: -1. This isn't really all that different from those who think that "Antichrist" refers to the pope etc. The answer would need evidence showing that it is a view held by a group of Christians, but **it shouldn't be a disallowed view**.

Comment: Whether the answer is anti-semite or not, if it is the doctrine of some official group of Christians, the answer should be permitted. If it's not (and I doubt that it is), it should be deleted.

Comment: @Flimzy is right.  Had the answer contained references to quotes from some recognized group and been from the angle of Group X believes that it's the European Jews", then it would have stood.  But that was not how it read.  it was presented as "It ***is*** the European Jews" with nothing to indicate that it's anything other than eliyah's *personal interpretation* of the Scriptures he quoted.  The same would go for answers stating that some group claims the Pope is the Antichrist.

Comment: Would it be fair that if @eliyah can provide some links showing that an identifiable group have taught the AoD refers to non-Christian Jews that the answer could be undeleted?

Comment: @curiousdannii - You happened to post that just as I was editing the answer.  Yes, that would be fair.

Comment: thank you for your fair re-evaluation of my answer.