# Why was "How many jews were in times of Jesus" on hold?

Tags: discussion

[This is actually a good question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30090/30). This actually reveals how many Jews were during the time of Jesus Christ. This will help to reveal the type of community where Jesus Christ lived and to whom he preached. It is an important part of christianity.

The problem is Caleb has been causing so many problems for me for a long time. I know he holds a personal grudge against me. But he wouldn't accept it. He just happens to be a moderator who wants to do the way he wants and there are couple of his friends here who accept lies as facts and denies the truth.

Comment: At least four people thought that question should be closed.  Caleb is not acting unilaterally.

Comment: @caleb lol @ you tidying up the post you're getting slagged off in - classy!

Answer (score 10):

This *might* be an OK question, just *not here*. Yes it's *tangentially related* to Christianity, but in general, it's not a question *about* Christianity. It's a question about Judaism/Israel/first-century history.

Those things are not on topic here. They *are* on topic on the History site, though the moderators decided (with agreement from SE staff in this particular case), that this question was not of sufficient quality to migrate.

As far as whether or not Caleb has a personal grudge against you, I cannot say. I can say that the answer you proffered, while interestingly relevant, was not an answer to the question per se, and at the very least made an odd semantic argument. If the question was deemed on topic, it might stay, but was already garnering quite the land slide of negative votes and your attitude in the comments might have led to deletion or suspension of your privileges.

Something that I need to say right now. If you want to continue to participate on this site you need to accept that your opinions will be one of many, that many versions of events are acceptable here and ultimately, *this community* will not make any considerations on what is and is not the truth. Most of us believe quite strongly that there *is* truth, but this site strives to be an *academic resource*, not a definitive source of truth. That's why we have [strict requirements for scoping related to truth questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1700/1304), so that alternative versions of the "truth" do not compete for votes and become a popularity contest.

Your behavior on this question does not lend itself to this kind of community, and your attacks on respected members of this site are unwelcome here. Please stop. No one has a vendetta against you, we evaluate users based on their *contributions*—not anything personal.

Answer (score 5):

As currently stated the question does not fit as it has no direct relation to Christianity.  If you can refine the question to ask about the relationship to Christianity, it could possibly be a better fit.

For example, something along the lines of "How did the demographics of the first century middle east impact the teachings of Jesus Christ?" would possibly be on topic, though almost certainly still too broad.

If it could be further narrowed down to ask about the cultural impact on a particular teaching, then it is probably addressable, though some cases may still be opinion based unless you also add a particular theological standpoint that you are looking for the views of.

The key thing to remember about this site is that it is not simply trying to find what is the True meaning of Christ's teachings, but rather trying to document what the views of the various groups that call themselves Christians are, regardless of the real world accuracy of these beliefs.

Most of us here DO have a view that we consider to be True, but the point of this site isn't to debate who is right or wrong.  There are lots of other sites out there that exist for that purpose.  This site exists to facilitate exchanging information about Christianity without the debates and arguments that are typical of trying to determine what Truth is.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend a *very* narrow question if this attempted. These are questions that have whole books (or more) devoted to them

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to keep this short and sweet.

1. As far as the "why" of the closure goes, I stand by my inital comment when I closed it:

   > This does not appear to be about Christianity either in belief, practice or history. This is really a world history question that just happens to partially touch on Christianity by way of comparision. You might try History but keep in mind you want to keep your question focused on one thing at a time.

   It might indeed be relevant TO Christians. It might be a very important thing to reference while researching in order to teach Christianity or about Christians. I was in no way making a judgement on the importance of the issue. What I was doing is saying that the expertise on this site is not the best expertise to address that subject. I sent the author towards the SE site that would be the most likely to be able to come up with the data he was looking for.
2. I have nothing against you personally. I don't know where you got that idea but if I have done anything personally against you please make me aware of my fault.

   On the other hand I am tasked with a certain role in this community (and as a matter of fact over on Biblical Hermeneutics as well). That includes helping make sure our questions and answers stay on topic and mitigating issues when people stray outside of the bounds of civil discourse. I ask that you take a step back and examine your attitude—maybe take a break from the keyboard and consider what you are trying to accomplish and how to most constructively go about that.
3. This is not about content or your ideas. No I do not agree with all of them, but that is *not the issue here*. The issue we're hitting here has nothing to do with whether what you are saying is lies or truth (incidentally nobody has even postulated another position so I'm not sure who is being accused of lies, but there you have it). The issue we're dealing with—that we need you to step back and try to get your head around—is what this site is for and how it works. Here are some posts that might be helpful in that regard. Please actually read them!

   - [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1379/30)
   - [How can anything outside of Bible, not be labeled as an opinion?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/30)
   - [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/30)
   - [How we are different than other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/30)
   - [What makes a good focused question?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/30)
   - [Why was my question closed? How can I get it open again?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/725/30)

Lastly, I cleaned up the comments on the main site post because there is no reason to subject the site newbie to the mess that had nothing to do with him *per se*, but for posterity here is the entire  thing. Anybody that likes can review how the whole thing went down to see that I'm not trying use my moderator position to suppress something:

[image: comments]

Comment: You have nested comments?! You ... you *heretic*!

Comment: @TRiG [Join me at the stake?](http://stackapps.com/q/2050/3583) It works a lot of the time but be ready for the mistakes it inevitably makes.

Comment: No thanks. I can't stand the things. (Nested comments are one of the reasons I don't hang out on Reddit or Slashdot.)